# Integration of postgreSQL on WAMP

Tags: php, postgresql, wamp, wampserver, postgresql-9.1

I have just installed the postgreSQL on windows 7. I am trying to integrate postgreSQL with WAMP server. 
For this i have done the following changes in httpd.conf and php.ini file

1 LoadModule `c:/path` to `libpq.dll` in `httpd.conf` and then

2 `extension=php_mod_pgsql.dll`, `extension=php_pgsql.dll` -- enable(reemove ;) in `php.ini`

If I do the above changes the localhost does not work.

If I do the second changes the localhost work but does not load the `libpq.dll`.

I checked the pgsql by php script by this

```
<?php
 echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'yes':'no';
 ?>
```

The script shows "yes", but apache is not loading the `libpq.dll`.
Now what i should do for load the postgreSQL into the Apache2.2* (wamp)

Answer (score 42):

1. After installation of [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/), you need to copy `libpq.dll` from `wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X` to  `wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2*\bin` . And restart the Wampserver.
2. Download **phpPgAdmin** [here](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phppgadmin/phpPgAdmin%20%5Bstable%5D/phpPgAdmin-5.0/phpPgAdmin-5.0.3.zip?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/&ts=1317978463&use_mirror=space).
3. Extract **phpPgAdmin-5.1.zip** in `C:\wamp\apps` So the path will be, `C:\wamp\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1`.
4. Create a file called `phppgadmin.conf` in `C:\wamp\alias`. And copy paste the following :

   > ```
   > Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/" 
   >
   > <Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/">
   >     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   >     AllowOverride all
   >         Order Deny,Allow
   >   Allow from all
   > </Directory>
   > ```
5. Left Click on the Wampserver Tray icon. Navigate to PHP > PHP extension. Then enable this

   > ```
   > a. php_pgsql 
   > b. php_pdo_pgsql extension.
   > ```
6. Open `C:\wamp\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.1\conf\config.inc.php`,

   a. find `$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = '';` change to `$conf['servers'][0]['host'] = 'localhost';`
   b. find `$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;` change `true` to `false`
7. Restart All service
8. Go to `http://localhost/phppgadmin/` and try to login.
9. Default Login credentials are

   - Username = "postgres"
   - Password = "root"

references :

1. [WAMP + PostgreSQL integration](http://www.plaatsoft.nl/wamp-postgresql-integration/)
2. [sourceforgenet phpPgAdmin downloadable for Windows with Wamp](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phppgadmin/phpPgAdmin%20%5Bstable%5D/phpPgAdmin-5.0/phpPgAdmin-5.0.3.zip?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/&ts=1317978463&use_mirror=space)

Comment: Thanks buddy it works! But what is the login credentials for login to phppgadmin?

Comment: Hey I salved this buddy I got the default password too:
Username = "postgres"
Password = "root".

Comment: This is still extremely helpful information! Thanks for answering this question. It solved all of my initial problems, but now I get a 403 error when I try to navigate to http://localhost/phppgadmin/ Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: nvm. found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414358/http-localhost-phppgadmin-403-forbidden)

Comment: make sure your paths for WAMP are right.  Mine is in `c:/wamp64/`

Comment: i am unable to copy the libpq.dll to the bin folder, it says the the file is being used,please close the folder.although all folders are closed

Comment: @sid.s: copying libpq.dll is showing that error because its used by a symlink (symbolic link) which might present in the wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2*\bin. removing or renaming this will allow you to copy in the folder.

Comment: I added "Require local" to the `phppgadmin.conf` file in `C:\wamp64\alias` to enable the use of phpPgAdmin (Source: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414358/http-localhost-phppgadmin-403-forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414358/http-localhost-phppgadmin-403-forbidden))

Answer (score 12):

Thank you. These instructions worked once I also added 
'Require local' to the phppgadmin.conf file:

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/" 

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/">
    Require local
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Adding 'Require local' helped me too. Thanks Jessica.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that WAMP has two `php.ini` files. One in Apache directory, one in php directory (`bin\php\php5.X.X`). Wampserver Tray manages the one in Apache directory.

To be able to run php cli tools (e.g `php artisan`), you need to uncomment the `php_pgsql` and `php_pdo_pgsql` in the `php.ini` in php directory.

Answer (score 1):

it worked thank you

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/" 

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phpPgAdmin-5.1/">
    Require local
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to start is with the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  It looks like the simplest fix is to set the `%PATH%` environment variable system-wide to include the path to libpq.dll.

Note that `%PATH` is searched last, so if a libpq is ever put into the system directory or the Apache directory it will be caught first.

Answer (score 0):

1. After Enabling Postgresql extension from WAMP icon i was able to get postgresql admin page but  `bin/cake bake all` command was failing with error 'php extn missing'.
   (referred @rails_id's post below to complete postgresql integration with WAMP)
2. checked in cmd prompt with `php -m`, no "*postgresql*" module was present.
3. Went to php installation directory, in my case it was "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.10" and enabled (removed the ;) following pg module in php.ini file:

   extension=pdo_pgsql
   extension=pgsql
4. restarted the wamp services.
5. `bin/cake bake all` is working fine from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are checking this page , but even after trying all the above and following other pages only for the reason that you have wamp already iinstalled .. then dont waste your time .

checkout below link 
https://bitnami.com/  which makes you wamp integration with postgreSQL damn easy ,without WAMP server :b ,

And now start your project right away !!