# http://localhost/phppgadmin/ -> 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, postgresql, wamp

I try to install postgreSql on my [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/)

So I follow some [tutorial](http://www.mickaelsylvestre.com/2013/07/installer-postgresql-avec-wamp/) and some other...

But when I access to `localhost/phppgadmin/`, an error occurs:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phppgadmin/ on this server.
```

Though I active php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql in PHP extensions...

My phppgadmin.conf:

```
# File phppgadmin.conf
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: Look at the Apache server error logs.

Comment: What version of WAMPServer have you got installed

Comment: Also can you show your \wamp\alias\phppgadmin.conf file, add it to your question and not as a comment please. This error is usually because you have made a mistake in the section that tell Apache which ip addresses it is allowed to show this alias to.

Comment: Done, I use Wampserver 2.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solve the problem by entering the line:

```
Require local
```

in the phppgadmin.conf:

```
# Fichier phppgadmin.conf
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: This put me in the right direction, my Alias path was wrong.  WAMP is in c:/wamp64/...

Answer (score 0):

For things such as PhpMyAdmin, PhpPgAdmin or other dangerous tools, you don't want to risk people from the Internet exploiting security holes in these programs. As a matter of fact web server logs are full of direct access to known vulnerabilities, often leading to 404 because they target an older version.

That being said, I would advise putting this in your configuration file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128 192.168.1.0/24
```

Replace `192.168.1.0/24` with your LAN or VPN subnet. An SSH tunnel is another secure option.

I am not one of these guys, but do know that if you encounter that kind of problem right after installing a package, your problem is probably adressed in the README made by the package manager. On Debian, this would have been `/usr/share/doc/phppgadmin/README.Debian`.