# WAMP - phppgadmin - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, phppgadmin

I'm trying to setup phppgadmin on a WAMP server, but when I go to:

```
http://localhost/phppgadmin
```

I get `403 Forbidden`.

Here's whats in the `C:/wamp64/alias/phppgadmin.conf` file:

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/"

<Directory "C:/wamp/apps/phppgadmin5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also tried adding `Require local` to this file because someone on another thread:
[http://localhost/phppgadmin/ -> 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414358/http-localhost-phppgadmin-403-forbidden)
said that solved the problem for them. It didn't change anything for me.

It works fine in Ubuntu I have installed in VirtualBox, but on Windows 10, everything related to programming is really awkward and problematic. I don't know what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your paths, your install is in `c:\wamp64` not `c:\wamp`

```
Alias /phppgadmin "C:/wamp64/apps/phppgadmin5.1/"

<Directory "C:/wamp64/apps/phppgadmin5.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And then restart the servers. (left click the system tray icon and Restart All Services)